# which is better for production with web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

which is better for production with web2py? please more insights.
I'm very new 2 web2py and i am working on a small pharmacy mgt system. 
pls which is better for production postgres or mysql? if postgres, step by step installation guide pls so to smoothly work with web2py. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is essentially a mysql vs postgres question -- which one is better for any specific task is a matter of much debate, especially because different criteria for "better" will bring different answers. _Maybe_ if you had more specific description of your application, data use, any replication required, it'd be more answerable, but the better approach would be for you to read more about them both and pick among them for reasons _you_ understand and hold for _important_.

Comment: @mark, i go online and check out forums, i see people asking all these questions on postgres. i've never used it but coming from php, i'm more conversant with mysql. so my question is why are there more questions with postgres tag? is it more robust? does it play better with web2py? is mysql a bad idea? which one does DAL embrace more? thank you.

Comment: @ sarnold, i would rather stay where am comfortable but would not want a situation where my clients will be on my neck all the time because of one thing or the other. like i said earlier, am just about 1 week on web2py. does the mailing list cover for all sort of problem?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think PostgreSQL is more popular among the web2py community, and there is even a section of the book discussing its [installation and usage with web2py](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#PostgreSQL). So, if you need assistance, it might be a little easier to get help with Postgres. On the other hand, if you're already familiar with MySQL, you might be better off sticking with what you know -- it should work just fine with web2py as well. Also, assuming you'll be using the web2py DAL, you can easily switch from one RDBMS to another without having to change any of your web2py code.

Answer (score 2):

I switched from PHP/MySQL (CakePHP, mostly) to web2py/PostgreSQL in the spring.  I can confirm that the web2py community is more oriented toward Postgres and you are more likely to find an answer to specific questions relating to the DAL if you use Postgres.  And you should check the licensing requirements of both systems to be sure that both match your business needs -- MySQL's licenses have undergone some changes recently with the change in ownership.

One thing to think about is that if you are new to web2py, you will be learning two new technologies at the same time, and both fundamental to your project.  I switched from being very comfortable on MySQL to very awkward on PostgreSQL.  I assumed -- wrongly, it turned out -- that SQL is SQL.  Well, just about every common command is totally different in Postgres.  The queries themselves are similar, but you likely won't be composing any manual queries anyway if you're using web2py; you'll be using the DAL syntax to query to DB.  At the least, take a good look at some [comparisons](http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/12/mysql-and-postgres-command-equivalents.html) between the commands of the two systems.  There's a world of difference.  Postgres commands are much shorter ("dt" instead of "show tables") but much less intuitive.

In short, PostgreSQL is a great RDBMS, but you may want to wait until you're comfortable with web2py before you switch.  The great thing about web2py and the DAL is that you *can* switch database systems, even after you've created your app.  You may face some hurdles if/when you switch databases, but you can get those straightened out here or on the web2py users e-mail list (on groups.google.com).

PS -- Regardless of which database you choose, unless your database schema is set in stone, be sure to take the time to fully understand the web2py DAL, particularly the uses of and differences between the "migrate" and "fake_migrate" arguments.  You will become well acquainted with [chapter 6 of the web2py book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06).

The good news is that the rest of web2py is a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I say. Whatever you can work with from console. Some events may require fixing db from fingertip, you may also want to have some other ongoing actions in db and it might need to be done outside web2py.

PosgreSQL is my choice as there are much less irregular behaviours thus its easier to grasp...

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use a DB noSQL like mongoDB. If you want to pay Informix is a good choise, however the best DB supported by web2py is postgres

1.postgres
2.mongoDB
3.Informix

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/

following list have all databases supported by web2py:

SQLite
PostgreSQL
MySQL
Oracle
MSSQL
FireBird
DB2 
Informix
Ingres
Cubrid
Sybase
Teradata
SAPDB
MongoDB 
IMAP